# How to Hide page layouts for particular user groups?

Tags: 2010, page-layout, custom

We have a requirement in which we have to hide a `custom page layout` for particular user groups. We have different custom page layout deployed on the site. Now user wants that one of the page layout should be visible to a particular user group no other groups can see that page layout.

Is it possible to achieve this?
If yes, Can you please suggest me how can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.